# Remove backslashes from a text file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have

Input:

```
 NISHA =\455
```

Output:

```
 NISHA = 455
```

I want to remove `\` from output. I tried to use command `sed "s/[\]//g" P` but it is not working and it flags an error:

```
character found after backslash is not meaningful
```

Comment: You seem to have a non-POSIX implementation of `sed` (or possibly you're running that command from a non-POSIX shell?). You don't need `sed` though, `tr` is enough: `tr -d '\\' < P`.

Answer (score 28):

You can either replace the backslash by a space as you show in the example result:

```
sed 's/\\/ /g'
```

or you can remove it as you show in your code:

```
sed 's/\\//g'
```

### Special characters

There are possible problems with escaping of backslash to cancel its special meaning. Backslash is a special character used for escaping both in a shell and in regular expressions.

The command you type to the shell's command line or a script is first processed by the shell which interprets the special meaning of characters and their escaping. The result is then passed to the command to be executed (like `sed`) which performs its own interpretation of the characters. When you are constructing a command the mental procedure is the opposite way: first add the escaping for the regex then add the escaping for the shell.

1. **In a regex** (input to commands like `sed`, `grep` etc.) backslash can be escaped by backslash like this: `\\` and also you can use the set expression `[\]` like you used because there backslash loses its special meaning.
2. **In a shell** (like `bash`) you can escape backslash by backslash. So instead of `\` write `\\`. Enclosing the string between double quotes `"` makes backslash behaviour more complicated[<sup><1></sup>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) but double backslash will still produce a single backslash. Enclosing the string between single quotes `'` makes every character to be treated literally except `'`.

If you want to use **double quotes**, you can use one of the following:
`sed "s/\\\\//g"` - Escape `\` by `\` in the shell, and escape every `\` in the regex again. In fact the double quotes are not necessary in this case because every special character is properly escaped.
`sed "s/[\\]//g"` - Escape in the shell by a backslash `\` and in the regex use a set `[` `]`.
`sed "s/[\]//g"` - Yes, your example should work in a POSIX compliant environment! Between double quotes `\` represents itself unless it precedes a special character in the context of double quotes: `` $`"\ `` or a newline. It looks like that in your case either the shell or the `sed` does not follow the POSIX standard.

With **single quotes** you can also use the string as you used or a shorter way:
`sed 's/[\]//g'`
`sed 's/\\//g'`

Answer (score 6):

You have to escape the backslash. Try this:

```
sed 's/\\//g'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want sed solutions, then try with following commands:

```
$ echo "NISHA =\455"| awk -F'\' '{print $1 $2}'
$ echo "NISHA =\455"| tr '\\' ' '
$ echo "NISHA =\455"| tr -d '\\'
$ echo "NISHA =\455"| cut -c 1-7,9-11
```

Answer (score 2):

In awk , i would do like this,

```
$ echo 'NISHA =\455' | awk '{gsub(/\\/," ")}1'
NISHA = 455
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\\//'
```

Place a `\` before `\` like you do with most special characters.

Comment: You have omitted the `g` flag for unknown reason. This changes the behaviour of the command but such a change was not asked for in the question. Otherwise your reply does not bring anything new in comparison to the earlier replies.