# Replacing File Content

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a file named EX.txt with content inside of it:

```
user='\''member'\''
```

I want to use sed to replace those '\'' to ' so it would be like this:

```
user='member'
```

But it didn't work when i use

```
sed -i "s/'\''/'/g" EX.txt
```

How to solve this?

Comment: The backslash needs to be escaped

Comment: @muru using [\] ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169209/70524